# pass an outer selects row variable to inner select in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you pass an outer selects row variable to inner select in oracle, here is a sample query ( other outer joins has been removed. This query will be loaded 1 time in life time of an application). This query works

```
select  l5.HIERARCHY_ID,
    (select wm_concat(isbn) isbns from (
        select  op.isbn from oproduct op
        LEFT JOIN  assignment ha on  op.r.reference = ha.reference
        where ha.hierarchy_id =  '100589'))isbns 
from level l5 where l5.gid = '1007500000078694'
```

but when I change the inner select's where clause

```
where ha.hierarchy_id =  '100589'))isbns 
to
where ha.hierarchy_id =  l5.HIERARCHY_ID))isbns
```

I get the following error
ORA-00904: "L5"."HIERARCHY_ID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this to fix the problem. There was one unnecessary select

```
select  
  l5.HIERARCHY_ID,
  (
    select  
      wm_concat(op.isbn) 
    from 
      oproduct op
      LEFT JOIN assignment ha on op.r.reference = ha.reference
    where ha.hierarchy_id =  l5.HIERARCHY_ID
  ) ISBNS
from 
  level l5 
where 
  l5.gid = '1007500000078694'
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pass the value of a 2nd level `SELECT`.

For example -

```
SELECT value1  -- 1st level select
FROM (
      SELECT value2  -- 2nd level select
      FROM ( 
            SELECT value3  -- 3rd level select.
```

You can have values from the 1st level `SELECT` available for only the second level `SELECT`.
Similarly the values in the second level `SELECT` are only available to the 1st level `SELECT` and the 3rd level `SELECT` not beyond that.

Comment: isnt' it other way around? value2 is available on 1st level select

Comment: This is the correct answer to this situation, surajz ended up removing one of the levels that is why it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think I am reading your SQL correctly - you want an outer join when the hierarchy ids match?

```
SELECT
    l5.hierarchy_id,
    op.isbns
FROM
    LEVEL l5
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT 
            wm_concat (op.isbn) isbns,
            ha.hierarch_id
        FROM
            oproduct op
            LEFT JOIN
                assignment ha
            ON op.reference = ha.reference) op
    ON l5.gid = op.hierarchy_id
```